# Automatically connect to APN with Android AOSP ROM

Tags: android, android-source, apn

I have built a custom ROM based on Android 4.4.4 custom ROM on Tilapia (Nexus 7).

When I put a SIM card in the device, the APN is not automatically added. It is a Free Mobile SIM card and this carrier is listed in /etc/apns-conf.xml. So I would expect this APN to be selected automatically like it does when I put this SIM card in any handset.

What am I doing wrong? How can I debug this issue?

Of course I can the APN manually through the settings but I want my device to have Internet access right after I flash it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution this is because the Provision package was missing in the generic_no_telephony.mk